# XML::XML2JSON "0" Element

Tags: xml, json, perl

I'm using [XML::XML2JSON](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::XML2JSON) in Perl to convert JSON data to XML, I am passing through the following data (snippet):

```
{"question":{"isrequired":{"$t":"0"}}}
```

and when I use the XML:XML2JSON->json2xml function to convert the JSON data into XML, I get the following (snippet):

```
<isrequired/>
```

I need to retain the "0" element in the "isrequired" tag, because at times, I will have empty JSON elements, and need the empty XML tag.  I think the documentation is a bit vague (either that, or I don't understand it), but is this possible to do with this module?

I would appreciate the help.  Thanks.

Comment: try placing `$t` in single quotes?

Comment: Hi Eric, I tried the single quote $t, and it still appears to have the same problem.. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a "zero but true" value instead of `"0"`:

```
" 0 "
" 0"
"0E0"
```

Comment: Thanks mobrule, I appreciate the help.  I'll just need to add some extra code on my part and it'll work!  Cheers.